# How to decode \u003d escape in bash?

Tags: bash, unicode, echo, zsh, xargs

I have some strings like:

```
dimension\u003d1920x1024:format\u003djpg
```

In a file. I want to decode them so they will look like:

```
dimension=1920x1024:format=jpg
```

I know that:

```
$ echo -e dimension\u003d1920x1024:format\u003djpg
dimensionu003d1920x1024:formatu003djpg
$ echo -e 'dimension\u003d1920x1024:format\u003djpg'
dimension=1920x1024:format=jpg
$ echo -e "dimension\u003d1920x1024:format\u003djpg"
dimension=1920x1024:format=jpg
```

So I tried this to get what I want:

```
$ cat file | xargs -L1 echo -e
dimensionu003d1920x1024:formatu003djpg
```

But as you can see it doesn't work. How can I get this to work? How can I make xargs pass parameters to echo as if they were quoted?

Comment: You need to change the base encoding of the file from Unicode to ASCII, using `echo -e` is not recommended

Comment: @Inian how? And what will happen then if there are actual Unicode characters in the file that are not in ascii won't the get encoded I want to use these in urls to feed them to wget?

Comment: Yes, the `\u003d` is a unicode sequence corresponding to `=`, can you get the output of your file `file <name-of-input-file>`, this will return the encoding file type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small files:

**Bash:**

```
cat file | echo -e "$(cat -)"
```

**Zsh:**

```
cat file | { echo -e "$(cat -)"; }
```

For large files in both bash and zsh:

```
cat file | while read -r LINE; do echo -e "$LINE"; done
```

(loses spaces at the beginning of the line)

Comment: `cat file | echo -e "$(cat -)"` does not do anything in zsh but works in bash.

Answer (score 3):

You are *actually* asking how to convert the sequence `\uXXXX` into the corresponding Unicode code point. That's quite different from other backslash escapes, or handling backslashes in general. Neither `echo -e` nor `xargs` is particularly suited for this task.

Here is one way:

```
perl -CSD -pe 's/\\u(\X{4})/chr(oct("0x$1"))/ge' <<<"string"
```

Obscurely, `oct("0xff")` actually performs hex decoding, because of the `"0x"` prefix.

Obviously, if your input is the text in a file rather than just a string in the shell, simply pass that as the argument to Perl.

Comment: Newish versions of Bash also support `\uXXXX` in `printf` format strings, but then of course you have to pick apart the string so you don't `printf` parts you *don't* want `printf` to parse.

Comment: I'm getting some strange behavior: I run this command: `perl -CSD -pe 's/\\u(\X{4})/chr(oct("0x$1"))/ge' html > decodedhtml`

Comment: Then I run `grep -Po '[^"]*http[^"]*' decodedhtml | wc` an I get that it has 17 lines. but If I do: `grep -Po '[^"]*http[^"]*' html | wc` I get 3805 lines.

Comment: By the way I get this msgs when I run your command but I ignored them:`Unicode non-character U+FFFF is illegal for open interchange at -e line 1, <> line 92.
Unicode non-character U+FFFF is illegal for open interchange at -e line 1, <> line 92.
Unicode non-character U+FFFF is illegal for open interchange at -e line 1, <> line 92.`

Comment: If your input contains `"\uffff"` you should examine the context and understand the meaning of this. You can skip this particular character or filter it out easily; `s/(?!\\uffff)\\u(\X{4})/.../` or just `s/\\uffff//g;` before the other code to remove all occurrences of this character. But again, look at the text you are processing and understand what it is before blindly modifying it in this way.

Comment: As an aside `grep -c` counts lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is a try with ruby where the changes are written to the file

```
$ cat ./file
dimension\u003d1920x1024:format\u003djpg
dimension=800x600:format\u003djpg
```

The example above is made a bit more real-world.

```
$ cat ./script.rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby
contents=File.read("#{ARGV[0]}")
file=File.open("#{ARGV[0]}","w")
if file
file.syswrite(contents.gsub(/\\[uU]\{?([0-9A-F]{4})\}?/i) { $1.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) })
file.close()
else
puts "No file with name #{ARGV[0]} present, Usage script <filename>"
end

$ ./script file
# The changes are written to the file with nothing printed to stdout
$ cat ./file
dimension=1920x1024:format=jpg
dimension=800x600:format=jpg
```

Comment: OP wants to use the `echo -e` to expand the UNICODE quotes to ASCII on a entire file, not sure how this helps

Comment: @Inian: Thanks for pointing that out. Later did I found out the op was playing with a file. Changed. But as you pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515348/how-do-decode-u003d-escape-in-bash#comment84025128_48515348), changing the base encoding of the file is of no use here as the problem deals with converting literal unicode codepoints to corresponding characters